# Why does Object.equals(Object o) require Object.hashCode() in java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, distinct, hashcode

I have a list of objects of type `Person` and I want to get rid of elements that have the same name, using streams. I have found on the internet a suggestion to use a *Wrapper class* and my code looks like this so far:

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person("Kowalski"),
                                    new Person("Nowak"),
                                    new Person("Big"),
                                    new Person("Kowalski"));

List<Person> distPeople = people.stream()
        .map(Wrapper::new)
        .distinct()
        .map(Wrapper::unwrap)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In documentation it is said that `distinct()`

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to
>   Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Implementation of `Wrapper` that doesn't work (I get the same stream with two *Kowalski*):

```
public class Wrapper
{
    private final Person person;

    Wrapper(Person p)
    {
        person = p;
    }

    public Person unwrap()
    {
        return person;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(other instanceof Wrapper)
            return ((Wrapper) other).person.getName().equals(person.getName());
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Implementation of `Wrapper` class works after adding this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return person.getName().hashCode();
}
```

Can someone explain why after overriding `hashCode()` in the `Wrapper` class `distinct()` works?

Comment: Because `distinct()` likely uses a `HashSet` for best performance. You should *always* implement [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) when you implement [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Irrespective of whether you are doing this with your objects, `equals` and `hashCode` should always be overridden together so as to yield consistent results. Otherwise you are violating the contract of `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the class `DistinctOps`. The method `makeRef` is used to return an instance of `ReferencePipeline` containing distinct elements. This method makes use of `LinkedHashSet` for performing a `reduce` operation in order to get distinct elements. Note that `LinkedHashSet` extends from `HashSet` which uses `HashMap` for storing elements. Now inorder for a `HashMap` to work properly, you should provide the implementation for `hashCode()` which follows the correct contract between `hashCode()` and `equals()` and therfore, it is required that you provide an implementation to `hasCode()` so that `Stream#distinct()` works properly.

Answer (score 2):

From equals Java doc

> It is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever
>   equals method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract
>   for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have
>   equal hash codes.

Please read the details about contract [here](https://javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html)

Comment: Seems you quoted the javadoc of `equals()`, so you should link to it.

Comment: But you didn't *link* to the source of the quote.

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct()` operation uses a `HashSet` internally to check whether it already processed a certain element. The `HashSet` in turn relies on the `hashCode()` method of its elements [to sort them into buckets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

If you don't override the `hashCode()` method, it falls back to its default, returning the object's identity, which usually differs between two objects even though they are the same according to `equal()`. Thus the `HashSet` puts them into different buckets and can no longer determine that they're the 'same' object.